# Syntax error, completing LocalVariableDeclarationStatement

Tags: java, syntax

There are many questions about this error here and I read many answers suggesting many solutions for it. I have already done some suggested changes and moved/added ";" around but the error comes back, i think the solution has to be individual for different codes, so I am asking you to help me and please could you suggest me some steps to fix the error?

`The error says: Syntax error, insert ";" to complete LocalVariableDeclarationStatement`

In the line:

`private static int lengthOfString String string; {`

The rest of the code is underneath to make it easier for you to see the error's cause. Please ignore the fact that the code is a total mess, I am only developing it and constantly changing it at the moment:

```
      import java.util.*;

public static void main(String[] args) {
  new LenthOfString2().method(); 
  { 
     System.out.println("Type your text...");

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 

    System.out.println(lengthOfString("I need your help programmers, please"));
}

private static int lengthOfString String string; {
    int length = -1;

    while (true) {
        try {
        string.charAt(++length);
        } catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException exception) {
            break;
        }
    }

    return length;

    System.out.println(sc.nextLine().length());

    sc.close();
}
```

I would like to mention that I am a beginner and I only understand basic java so any help from you will be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Ah ..my eyes ...please format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `method signature` was not correct.

**Method signature should have modifier, return type, method name, parameters in parentheses.**

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Type your text...");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Length of String: " + lengthOfString("I need your help programmers, please"));
        sc.close();
    }

    /**
     * Calculates the length of given string. Returns an integer.
     * 
     * @param string
     * @return 
     */
    private static int lengthOfString(String string) {
        int length = -1;
        while (true) {
            try {
                string.charAt(++length);
            } catch (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException exception) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return length;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I also added some little changes to the corrected code by you to meet my specific needs and now it works perfectly and no errors! Thank you for letting me know what was exactly wrong with the code and correcting me, i am a java beginner so it helped me a lot.